# Time picker validation return always false

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm Using the daterangepicker library and validating my form by javascript validation but time field return false it says (Please enter a valid time, between 00:00 and 23:59 ) Means it not allowing me to add time like (08:25 AM)

This is my validation  code

```
var $validationForm = $('#smartwizard');
            $validationForm.validate({
                errorPlacement: function errorPlacement(error, element) {
                    $(element).parents('.form-group').append(
                        error.addClass('invalid-feedback small d-block')
                    )
                },
                highlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element) {
                    $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
                },
            });
```

This is my time picker function

```
$(document).on('focus','.time',function(){
                $(this).daterangepicker({
                 timePicker : true,
                singleDatePicker:true,
                timePickerIncrement : 1,
                timePicker24Hour:false,
                timePickerSeconds : false,
                locale : {
                    format : 'hh:mm A',
                }
            }).on('show.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
                picker.container.find(".calendar-table").hide();
                });
        });
```

Comment: `08:25 AM`  doesn't seem to match `format : 'hh:mm A'`. Does `08:25 A` work? (Or changing the format to `'hh:mm AM'`?)

Comment: 'hh: mm A' is format by moment.js  for time 12 hrs format

Comment: it only let me enter time in 24 hrs Format not in 12 hrs format  if i use 'HH : mm' format instead 'hh: mm A'

Comment: I think it is a validation issue how could I stop validation for some field in the form

Comment: I googled your `.validate` method, and if it's from this library, there's an `ignore` method: https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore. Of course you might want to write custom code to make sure the field is not empty or matches your specified format. (Alternatively, you could let the user enter a time in one field, then convert their 12-hr time into 24-hr time to populate a hidden field that gets validated, but that gets pretty hacky.)

Comment: ignore, still doesn't work for me but input type time without validation provide  12 Hrs format as needed :) Thanks For supporting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace class name `.time` to any `class name` because of daterangepicker assume time for 24 hours format.